# Accessing the main app after a Push Notification on Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

On our app, one of the consistent bugs we've been notified about is something going wrong in our `LocalBroadcastReceiver` (normally phones with outdated Android versions on them that don't have some function or other).  We get an ok stacktrace from Google Play, but in our main app, we've a `UncaughtExceptionHandler` that posts stacktraces and the like to a bug tracking system we're using.  Along with the stacktrace, we also send some of their profile within the app.

The thing is, the receiver is in a separate thread with the settings,

```
<receiver
android:name="com.sixminute.gcm.LocalBroadcastReceiver"
android:process=":remote"
/>
```

When the bug occurs, if we check the profile, everything is completely blank.  I'm assuming that is because the thread for the receiver is completely separate from the main app but I am not really sure.

Whatever the setup is, is there any way I can communicate from that thread to the main one that has all the profile information of the user?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar issue and my problem was related to having `android:process=":remote"` in the receiver definition. When you specify this element, Android makes the receiver run in that process, which may or may not be the same process as where the user profile data is currently stored in.

My application had two processes - one background service that started up automatically at boot time and a separate process containing the UI for the app - and the advantage of having two separate processes is that we could kill and restart the service without making the UI go down with it too.

To fix your problem, make sure that the receiver runs on the same process as the component that contains the data that you're looking for, or configure an UncaughtExceptionHandler for the ":remote" process. An easy way to do the latter is by creating an `Application` (as in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)) and configuring the default ExceptionHandler in there instead of configuring it in your app's activities and/or services.